# How to get Email id of the user in v2.4 facebook sdk?

Tags: javascript, facebook, email, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to get the email id of the user by using facebook sdk through javascript but I am unable to get it. The same function will return an email ID before.  Please find the code below that Iam using to get the email id of the user.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email', function(response) {
        alert("JSON "+JSON.stringify(response));
    });
```

Comment: Log your access token to console, and [debug it](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see if it actually contains the `email` permission.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the AppId?

```
FB.init({
appId      : 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID', // App ID
status     : true, // check login status
cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
```

You can test the [Graph Api here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.4).

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited my answer :) You need to configure your FB SDK.